# Issue while picking JKS file from java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jks

1. JAVA 8
2. JKS files
3. Application Server Weblogic

When I try to read my JKS file from java code, it says File now found exception.
Because when i checked the deployment package, I found that my jks files are placed under `xx/WEB-INF/lib/_xs_gen.jar/<MY_FILE>.jks` and hence the jks is not picked. Can jks file are readable under jar.
Can someone help me? how or where to put the jks file so that it will be picked.

Note: I am just passing my jks file path to kafka producer code. which means when the message is trying to push that time we need jks to have a secure a connection.

Comment: Please show the part of your code where you pass the JKS file path to Kafka. Maybe there is a way to do that without an actual file. But how did your file end up in this jar file? And why doesn't it have a name (just an extension)?

Comment: Looking at the Kafka docs, you probably have to put the JKS into an actual file somewhere (not inside a JAR file).

Comment: Thilo, The file has a name kafka_event.jks I must forgot to put here. and i think my packaging is an issue which put that file under jar file. i need to look into that.